# Can I handle customer code in optional dll?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a core part of my c# winforms application. Most of my customers use this core version. Now a customer requested some modifications and extensions. I would like to seperate this from the core part because it is not useful in the core. My idea is to use polymorphism. I would put the overriding parts in a sepearate ddl. Now I would do something like: If the customer dll is present, then use this. If not, run the core. I have no idea if this is the best approach and how to implement it. Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like an idea and it might work but that depends on your coupling and what you intend to swap out. What specifically is not working? What else did you research to figure out if his will work for you? Another alternative is to use DI / IoC and a tenant structure. Good luck.

Comment: I am at the very start. I just thought about polymorphism and did not try anything yet. I want to make the first steps correctly when I think about the future and maintainabilty: I might have 100 customers running the core version and 20 customers running modifications. Now I am updating a core dll and want to make sure that everything is still running without exceptions - including the 20 mods ...